# App Intro Page in Android

Tags: android, showcaseview

I want to show a UI for explaining the app.It exists in many apps. It's shown when the user start the app for the first time. 
Unfortunately I don't have an image to explain, so I hope somebody will understand what I'm talking about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to do prior searching before posting a question.

Anyways here are couple of libraries which will definitely help you to achieve your goal.

1. [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) but it's kind of out-dated.
2. [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) most of the latest apps show something like this as intro to app for users. And it also is Material.

   3. [MaterialIntro](https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro) is another good library which can provide an intro for users

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask for Use ShowCase View

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/README.md) Library, 
Add by:

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.0'
```

To use it:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this) .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME)) .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView") .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button") .hideOnTouchOutside() .build();
```